# Background a process and execute something with one command

Tags: shell, command-line, background-process

Probably it would be easier to do just with a script, but I wonder why can't I do that with one command. What I have tried so far:

```
$ (ls >/dev/null &) && echo $!
3135
$ (ls >/dev/null &) ; echo $! #bad idea, but if that worked, I could just add `sleep 0.1`
3135
$ ls >/dev/null & ; echo $!
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
$ `ls >/dev/null &` && echo $!
3135
$ `ls >/dev/null &` ; echo $!
3135
```

The `3135` number is a PID of a last backgrounded process which holds the variable `$!`, and it remains unchanged *(also I am using Konsole and for backgrounding a process succeed, it would print something like `[1] PID`)*. Alas, neither of the executed commands sends the process to a background.

Comment: not sure to understand, you want to lauch a backgroup process that will take unknow amount of time (let say 10 minutes) and know immediatly the result ?

Comment: @Archemar it isn't important how long it going to take for a process to end, the PID would be returned *(almost)* immediately. Initially I was need it to launch a process and gdbserver with it's PID with one command.

Comment: Have a look [How do I run only first command in backgound?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/538894/how-do-i-run-only-first-command-in-backgound)

Comment: @KasiyA funny, but for some reason neither of a ways in the suggested there answer worked here.

Comment: @KasiyA ah, I just got why. The wurtel's answer explains this: just the `$!` variable didn't updated these ways ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
$ ls > /dev/null & echo $!
```

Because you were forcing the background command into a subprocess in all sorts of ways, the first shell did not have any background process and hence `$!` was not updated.

Now the background process is started by the same shell that gets to do `echo $!` so now it does what you want.

Comment: Here's one thing I don't understand though: why is this command launches two applications? Aren't using of two application should be separated with something? Semicolon, or `&&`, or something… In fact your answer works, but from what I know it should have been triggered a syntax error.

Comment: The `&` is a separator just like `;` except that `;` tells the shell to wait for the first command to complete before proceeding with the next, while `&` tells the shell to put the first command in the background and to proceed directly with the next.